# .net development dynamically created controls need their own methods

Tags: asp.net, javascript, code-behind, server-side

I'm sure that almost everyone programming in .net has ran into similar issues with the dynamic creation of buttons..

Example scenario..

I have a gridview and in one of the gridview fields I have a button. Normally in .net using visual studio you can easily grab the click event of the button, however since these buttons are dynamically created they're not as easy to grab. I was curious to what the best method for grabbing the button's click event would be.

I understand its possible using dopostback; however, I'm not sure how to implement it nor have I tried because I have also read dopostback method is not a very good one to use. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, the answer was much simpler than I ever thought..

I didn't realize that the ItemCommand event was usable for buttons created in a TemplateField.

All I really had to do was..

```
Private Sub GridView1_ItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsViewCommandEventArgs) Handles DetailsView1.ItemCommand
    If e.CommandName = "myButton" Then
        //'myButton press event logic here
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help guys.. I really appreciate it. Your answers will be helpful in the future I'm sure.

Answer (score 4):

In the gridview, there is an event called [RowDatabound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx).  Put an event handler on that:

> ```
> gv.RowDataBound += new EventHandler(rowBound);
> ```

Now inside that function, you'll use FindControl to locate the button and add a handler:

> ```
> function rowbound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
> {
>   if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
>   {
>       var b = e.Row.FindControl("btn") as Button;
>       b.Click += new EventHandler(handleBtnClick);
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: I think goodwince is asking how to set an event handler to a dynamically created control inside a gridview.  cmsjr's answer seems to fit better.

Answer (score 2):

During the ItemCreated event of the Gridview use FindControl to get a reference to the button and attach the event handler there. ie. btn.Click += Somehandler;